90s live-action sci-fi kids' show involving two boys fixing a ship and a girl who is placed under mind-control by the villain
It's not Hypernauts, but the first episode had something similar.
So during the (mid?) 90s, I was at a friend's house and they had their TV playing a live-action, kids' based sci-fi show.
From what I remember, there were two boys in a ship attempting to fix it while a girl was exploring the area. She comes upon an alien creature, which then hides when the villain approaches the girl and places a mind-control device on her. They walk away, leaving a concerned alien creature behind.
My friend's dad then changed the channel because he thought it was scaring me. LOL
Is there someone who can solve this problem for me?

It's a pretty common error, but [tag:fantasy-genre] and [tag:science-fiction-genre] are only meant to apply to discussions of the genre. I've fixed your tag to the story-identification one.
